# react-router-dom basename in BrowserRouter is not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I created a ReactJs application and what to be accessible only in *domain.com/**app***.

I added this to `index.js`

```
<BrowserRouter basename='/app/'>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

And now when I navigate between pages it works as it should (it adds `/app/` properly), ex. `domain.com/app/about`.

But the application is still being accessible without `/app`, ex. when I type `domain.com/about` still shows the about page.

While I want it bo be accessible only with `/app/`, and not without it.

Answer (score 7):

it seems that you have accidently added a trailing slash, which is not required.

see https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string for more details.